# Methodology structure for undergraduate thesis

Tags: thesis, bachelor, methodology

This is a very basic question, hope you can help me. I study abroad and I am working on my final year thesis. My thesis subject relates to the field of finance. In the literary review I establish a mathematical background of various theories. In the methodology I develop algorithms that use real data and are based on the previous literary review. The thesis structure I must follow is asking me to specify whether my research is quantitative or qualitative, I must also further specify which kind, so for example if it's quantitative, is it descriptive, correlational, etc.? I know my methods revolve around a quantitative nature, but then again I can't think of how a descriptive, correlational research would apply to my thesis. I have talked to my tutor but he's shown very little interest in helping me. I was considering dropping this part of the thesis structure because I just feel it does not apply. What could I do?

Comment: This depends on how many variables you are looking at in the data and how you intend to analyze them. There are lots of possibilities and you only list two options.